# In java and android how to add views in an arraylist?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create `ArrayList` of views. Unfortunately, the `ArrayList` values changes as the views reference changes.

I have two references, one to add at even position and another at odd. I see the behaviour as when 3rd item comes, the value of 1st also changes and same applies for the even number also.

I need to update the list of views on some bases. How this can be solved? I tried it by something like this but didn't worked:

```
  private void addItemAt(int depth,View retView){

    ArrayList<View> viewsAdded = new ArrayList<View>(viewsAtDepths.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < viewsAtDepths.size(); i++) {
        View v = viewsAtDepths.get(i);
        viewsAdded.add(v);
    }

    viewsAtDepths = viewsAdded;

    if(depth < viewsAtDepths.size()){
        Log.d(TAG,"Replacement at depth "+depth);
        viewsAtDepths.set(depth, retView);
    }
    else{
        Log.d(TAG,"Added at depth "+depth);
        viewsAtDepths.add(retView);
    }

    Log.d(TAG,"ADD item is made "+depth +" and total nu of items are      "+viewsAtDepths.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < viewsAtDepths.size(); i++) {

        if(viewsAtDepths.get(i) instanceof ListView){
            ListView lv = (ListView) viewsAtDepths.get(i);
            if(lv.getItemAtPosition(i) instanceof Node){
                Node n = (Node) lv.getItemAtPosition(0);
                Log.d(TAG,"Title Name at "+i+" selected node is "+n.title);
            }
            else{
                if(lv.getItemAtPosition(i) instanceof String){
                    Log.d(TAG,"String Title Name at "+i+" selected node is "+lv.getItemAtPosition(i));
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please make your post/question clearer, as it is quite hard to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you want to check out adapters. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html